# Can I fill_in a field, if it is wrapped in (display:none)?

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, capybara

Is there a way to fill_in a field that looks like so...

```
<span id="you_cannot_see_me" style="display: none;">              
    <input id="hidey" name="hidey" type="text" value="">          
</span>
```

I have tried...

```
accessthis = find('#hidey').should_not be_visible
fill_in( accessthis , :with => 'desired text')
```

...and receive the following error

```
Unable to find field false (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Selenium you cannot interact with webelements that are not visible.
Selenium is used to mimic actual user interactions, so anything that you cannot do manually cannot be done with Selenium.

Comment: If you absolutely need to fill in the text field, you can use a javascript injection to make the `span` visible, fill in the text field, and return the `span` to `display:none` when you are finished.